# Regex to match specific numbers and hyphen

Tags: jquery, regex

I have the following code that works. I need to have this format:
`9999999.9999` or `-9999999.9999`

So 7 numbers before the decimal and 4 after decimal and the ability to have an hyphen as well.

I believe this will allow hyphens: `(?!^-)`. I am not sure how to make it all work. Here is my code.

```
var state = undefined;

$('.numeric-decimal-114').on('input', function(event) {             
  var val = $(this).val();        
  var regex1 = new RegExp(/^(\d{1,7}|\d{0,7}\.\d{0,4})$/g);
  if (!regex1.test(val) && val !== "") {
    $(this).val(state);
    return;
  }
  state = val;
});
```

Comment: `\d{1,7}|\d{0,7}` is equivalent to `\d{0,7}`.

Comment: so add add an optional - on the front

Comment: If there *has* to be be 7 & 4 chars then use `\d{7}` and `\d{4}`

Comment: The way I have works. The problem I want the ability to be able to add an hyphen

Comment: Why was it flag as duplicate? I did search and could not find an answer.